# jQuery: $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_div")

Tags: jquery, this, selector

I'm trying to modify a name-related element. I'm taking values from a drop-down and displaying them in a div. Their ids are:
selected_terms
selected_terms_div

I have a number of these pairs and I was hoping to write generalized code instead of hard-coding it (I figure it'll be useful later).

This code isn't working:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_div")
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Whole script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("#selected_terms option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + '<br>';
              });

          $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_div").html(str);
    })    
        .change();
});
```

Note: It works if I change that line to:

```
$("#selected_terms_div").html(str);
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to solve your problem. Please post more of your JavaScript. The little snippet in your question seems fine.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  What error do you get?  Also, can you show more context around the call?  In particular I'm interested in what the value of 'this' might be - 'this' can be a little tricky sometimes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working. You guys were right. It seems right because it is. Thanks for responding.